# How to pass input data from template to the component class in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components

I am trying to pass the data which is in the input field to the component class

This is my *component-class* **alpha.js**

```
@tracked choice;

    @action next() {

        console.log(this.choice);
    }
```

This is my *template* **alpha.hbs**

```
    <Input @value={{this.choice}} type="radio"  />
    <button onclick={{action 'next'}}>Next</button>
```

So far it is returning empty.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Input` component is designed to text inputs. For radio buttons you need to do some manual work. A simple approach could look like this:

```
<input value="one" type="radio" {{on "change" this.change}} />
<input value="two" type="radio" {{on "change" this.change}} />
<button onclick={{action 'next'}}>Next</button>
```

With this `change` action:

```
@action change(event) {
  this.choice = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
but just for clarification
I know that this.change is calling the action from component-class. but
{{on "change" this.change}} Is the "change" a parameter to the change action here being passed to component class as event?

Comment: This is the `{{on` modifiert. It basically calls `addEventListener`, and `change` is the first parameter to `addEventListener`. So it will fire for the `change` event